# SocketException on Windows XP home edition on connect: an invalid argument was supplied

Tags: c#, sockets, socketexception

Our software needs to connect to an server and we do that with use of an TCPclient.
50+ systems (all Windows XP pro) are using the software and have no problem with connecting.
The software also has been tested on windows vista an Windows 7 beta.

Today there are some external people here for training and one of them has a laptop with **Windows XP Home** edition, which fails to connect to the server with SocketExeption "an invalid argument was supplied". (windows socket exception code: 10022)

However, when we try to telnet to that ip and port on the same laptop we can make a connection.

The code to connect is very basic:

```
m_client = new TcpClient();
m_client.Connect(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(host), port);
```

Are there any additional socketoptions we have to set on Windows XP Home edition?

About his system:
Windows XP Home edition version 2002 Service pack 2
One network-card active: Broadcom 440x 10/100 Integrated Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for people who wonder. We never got the time to further investigate the issue. It seemed to be a problem with the host's pc...